# Part of transparency doesn't appear

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a progblem wih rendering in transparency - I have a transparent field tiecked in Film, and when I render my texture looks like that (2 photo) when I moved the png file to phooshop - it changes completelyy. How can I fix it?

[image: Photoshop][image: Render in blender]

Comment: Do you have RGBA selected under 'Color' in the output settings? There's a tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/GyDAPQHiy3A) on rendering transparent png files.

Comment: @JohnEason yes, RGBA is selected

Comment: I'm not familiar with Photoshop, but if you watch the video I linked to it appears to work fine there.

Comment: I checked the tutorial - I have everything in place in Blender. The object also looks bad when I open the render as an image on the computer. It doesn't matter if it's photoshop or windows window. It only looks good when I render it without transparency.

Comment: Have you checked that the normals are correct? - In Edit mode, select All then Alt-N > Recalculate Outside.